# How to execute a task at an interval and also in response to external signal?

Tags: project-reactor

Imagine a task that executes repeatedly, with a delay of at most 10 seconds between each execution. There is also an external signal that causes the task to execute immediately. (After the external signal, it does not matter whether the timer is reset back to 10 seconds.)

I've tried modeling this is two ways, but neither is ideal:

1. Use a `Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(10))` for timer-based execution. Use a hot Flux created from `Sinks.many()` which gets fed the external signal.  Merge the two fluxes, and execute the task in a `concatMap` operator on the result of the merge.

   The problem with this approach is that the signals can "pile up" ahead of the execution. Adding an `onBackpressureLatest()` mitigates heap exhaustion, but doesn't prevent several signals from getting queued up if one execution of the task takes longer than the delay interval.
2. Add a `delay()` followed by a `repeat()`. The challenge here is that I can't figure out how to get the delay to reliably end early when the hot external trigger flux emits a value. `Mono.firstWithValue` is *almost* what I want, but it subscribes to the external trigger flux each time, which means it's possible to miss a signal.

How can this sort of task scheduling be implemented using Reactor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look into [`Flux.windowTimeout(int, Duration)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#windowTimeout-int-java.time.Duration-) With `windowTimeout(1, Duration.ofSeconds(10))`, the resulting outer Flux will emit inner Fluxes that end whenever one element is received, or when 10 seconds have passed, whichever comes first. Then you can attach your task to the end of the windows.

Example:

```java
Flux<String> externalSignalFlux;

public Mono<String> task() {
    return Mono.just("Task completed");
}

public Flux<String> windowTimeoutDemo() {
    return externalSignalFlux
            .windowTimeout(1, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .concatMap(window -> window.then(task()));
}
```

If you need to process the value of the signal:

```java
Flux<String> externalSignalFlux;

public Mono<String> task(String signal) {
    return Mono.just("Task completed: " + signal);
}

public Flux<String> windowTimeoutDemo() {
    return externalSignalFlux
            .windowTimeout(1, Duration.ofSeconds(10))
            .concatMap(window -> window.defaultIfEmpty("repeatedTask"))
            .concatMap(this::task);
}
```

Note: While [`Flux.bufferTimeout(int, Duration)`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#bufferTimeout-int-java.time.Duration-) looks very similar, the timeout for each window only starts when the first element is received, causing gaps in the resulting Flux.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using this code snippet. I simplified your case but it should be good to further improvements.

```
private static final Integer TIMEOUT = 10;

@Test
void shouldReactOnTriggerOrProvideDefaultValue() {
    trigger()
        .flatMap(trigger -> task())
        .timeout(Duration.ofSeconds(TIMEOUT), task())
        .log()
        .as(StepVerifier::create)
        .expectNextCount(1)
        .verifyComplete();
}

private Mono<String> trigger() {
    return Mono.just("trigger")
        .delayElement(Duration.ofSeconds(new Random().nextInt(TIMEOUT)));
}

private Mono<String> task() {
    return Mono.just("task");
}
```